# How do I know if my cast contains too many characters?

Tags: characters, technique, character-development, numerals, concept

I have one MC that will discover more about themselves, and in that, they will discover the different parts of themselves — their psychology and their hidden desires. The deeper the person, the more different parts/people that will show about themselves, but they are not the only one who will be doing that. Other characters will discover themselves and their own psychology.

Now here's the thing, each of those "different parts" are presented as the character, but with a similar or different designs.  I am not sure if I want them to be considered as "characters" since it will make the cast too big. Maybe I shouldn't make them as characters or simply just erase the other characters and let the MC be the only one experiencing this.

Comment: Hi, does this answer your question? [How many characters are too many?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/37699/34330)

Comment: Are you talking about multiple identity, or am I confused?

Comment: The linked question has a specific set-up. It will depend on a lot of factors such as length, audience, genre, and writing style. And on personal preference. Dostoevsky or Tolstoy wrote some novels with complex lists of characters and relationships to keep track of, and others where there is essentially only one character who undergoes anything significant.

Answer (score 1):

The first test is for you to name them all, from memory, including their jobs, roles in the story, and personality details. If you can’t name them all, or if you confused them, then you might have too many

Another test, is to examine all the characters and their actions that drive the story forward. Ask yourself could this action be performed by another character.  If you find that some characters are needed for the things that are driving the story forward, nix them.